# Update query SQLite gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have used db=this.getWritableDatabase(); in the constructor itself, so I havent used a specific open or close function. Should I?

```
public void changeCabLocation(String to_loc, String cab_id2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues val=new ContentValues();
    val.put(cab_location, to_loc);
    db.update(TB_cabs, val, cab_id+"="+cab_id2, null);
}

public void changeDriverLocation(String to_loc, String driver_id2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues val=new ContentValues();
    val.put(driver_location, to_loc);
    db.update(TB_drivers, val, driver_id+"="+driver_id2, null);
}
```

Comment: Please share the logcat, mention the specific line your error occurs, and a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
db.update(TB_cabs, val, "cab_id=?", new String[] {cab_id2});
```

Comment: How does that fix NPE?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I've written try. But to me it seems not very reasonable that cab_id (and driver_id) is holding a column name and yes a column value. Was that a wrong assumption?

Comment: Without the logcat, we can't be clear what is null. So you could be correct, but also not.

Comment: I agree, for sure.